# First Windows Azure App - Where is the Assets folder?

Tags: azure

I downloaded the Windows Azure Platform Training Kit - [WAPTK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=413e88f8-5966-4a83-b309-53b7b77edf78&displaylang=en) and started with the first exercise Ex1-BuildingYourFirstWindowsAzureApp . At Task 3 I get stuck though. The problem is that I can't find the 'Assets' folder.

"In the Add Existing Item dialog, browse to the Assets folder in the Source\Ex1-BuildingYourFirstWindowsAzureApp for the language of your project (Visual C# or Visual Basic), hold the CTRL key down while you select every file in this folder and click Add."

Anyone had the same problem ? When is the Assets folder created ?

Comment: What is WAPTK? I asume you mean Windows Azure Platform Training Kit? It would be useful if you could provide a link for those less familiar.

Comment: @Steve: Indeed. The WAPKT can be foudn here:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=413e88f8-5966-4a83-b309-53b7b77edf78&displaylang=en

Comment: Cool. I've taken the liberty of editing your question to add the link directly in there.

Answer (score 0):

In my install it appears to be here

```
C:\WAPTK\Labs\BuildingAppsWithCacheService\Source\Assets
```

but I agree the docs are not at all clear.

Answer (score 0):

WAPTK is the [Windows Azure Platform Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=413e88f8-5966-4a83-b309-53b7b77edf78&displaylang=en). The last release was June 2012.

For each Lab there is generally a Begin folder, End Folder and an Assets folder to get code from.
There is also normally Visual Studio snippets to install, plus for some other labs there are also other installations.

When you open the Menu - normally installed into WAPTK\Labs\Labs.htm - each lab has 4 links
Lab Manual - Lab Files - Setup Lab - Setup Instructions

Its a good idea to click on Setup Lab first, install whatever is necessary. Then click on Lab Files which will give you the starting solutions, then the Lab Manual to follow.

On my Install I have the following folders

```
WAPTK\Labs\IntroductionToWindowsAzureVS2010\Source\Ex1-BuildingYourFirstWindowsAzureApp\CS\Assets
WAPTK\Labs\IntroductionToWindowsAzureVS2010\Source\Ex1-BuildingYourFirstWindowsAzureApp\CS\Begin
WAPTK\Labs\IntroductionToWindowsAzureVS2010\Source\Ex1-BuildingYourFirstWindowsAzureApp\CS\End
```

Answer (score 0):

It is found here:

```
DRIVE:\WATK\Labs\IntroToCloudServices\Source\Ex1-BuildingYourFirstWindowsAzureApp\Assets
```

This is the latest Training Kit as of June 2012